# Get Path in a ListBox of all Open Explorer Windows

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vbscript, windows-explorer

I want to list all open Windows Explorer windows with their active path in a `ListBox`. The app should refresh the `ListBox` if the explorer window is navigated to a different path.

For e.g. two explorer windows are open. One is navigated to `C:\Windows` and the other is navigated to `D:\Stuff`. When the app it run, it adds `C:\Windows` and `D:\Stuff` to the `ListBox`. Then, the user navigates to a different folder in one of the open explorer windows like `C:\Windows\system32`. The app should then refresh the `ListBox` and list `C:\Windows\system32` and `D:\Stuff` instead.

I don't have any ideas on how to do this. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you can find an example how to access the paths in `WindowsExplorer` and `InternetExplorer` : http://omegacoder.com/?p=63

What about to be able to receive a notification about the fact that user navigated to different path, there is no way that I'm aware of, honestly.

So the first solution that comes to my mind, is use a `Timer` and check on every tick.

Comment: It  *should*, cause `WindowsExplorer` btw is always there.

Comment: @Programmer: not that I'm aware of.

Comment: What about Firefox? how to do the same?

Comment: @Tigran The link is dead

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma: the path does work. there was propbably some temporary shut down  ...