# get report of all open explorer windows

Tags: powershell, windows-8, windows-7, explorer

I want to get a report of all open explorer windows titles and current paths.  The current paths part of this is problem is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742127/get-path-of-all-open-explorer-windows) with C#, but I want this for powershell and am not sure how to adapt it.
I am not sure how to bring out the window titles part of it.

Could someone please assist.

Comment: Have you tried anything in powershell? Getting any specific errors?

Comment: I am have not tried anything yet.  Primarily because I dont know how to use ShellWindowClass with powershell.  
And due to the fact that Windows explorer embeds all its processes, I cant use get-process to do anything like get-process | echo $_.mainWindowTitle

Comment: Based on Ansgar's answer:  `LocationName` is the property containing name of the Window, as used in the task bar.  Using his answer, you can see `LocationName` with:  
 `$app.Windows() | Select-Object LocationURL, LocationName`   
... `LocationName` works, as is, for local folders.   
*(Remote folders also contain the unc name in parentheses (\\

Comment: @MikeD: `LocationName` is the name of the _location_, which may or may not be the same as the _window_ title; somewhat obscurely, it is the `.Document.Folder.Self.Path` property that contains the location's full local or UNC path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're looking for something like this:

```bsh
$app = New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application'
$app.Windows() | Select-Object LocationURL
```

AFAICS the window objects don't have a title property, but you can get that information from [`Get-Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process) via the window handle ID:

```bsh
function Get-WindowTitle($handle) {
  Get-Process |
    Where-Object { $_.MainWindowHandle -eq $handle } |
    Select-Object -Expand MainWindowTitle
}

$app = New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application'
$app.Windows() |
  Select-Object LocationURL, @{n='Title';e={Get-WindowTitle $_.HWND}}
```

Comment: This is one more step on the process.  If I am inferring properly, this give me the ShellWindowsClass part of the equation, but I also want to get the application titlebar from it. 
 
ie  
Titlebar          LocationURL  
C:\dir1            file://c:/dir1  
C:\dir2            file://c:/dir2  
  
Sidenote: tested LocationName from that area, and have actually added it to my final choice, since some locations may not have a LocationURL (like Devices and printers, etc..)
(sorry after multiple edits, I cant seem to get line breaks to work.)

Comment: Windows explorer has to have the information somewhere, because it is displayed in the taskbar, Unless they just do a conversion between the Location URL format nomenclature to an older standard DOS style nomenclature.

PS sorry for the delay, I was off line for a few days.

Comment: guess I will settle for the half I have for now,

Comment: `LocationName` is the property containing name of the Window, as used in the task bar.  Using what you have started, you can see this with:  
 `$app.Windows() | Select-Object LocationURL, LocationName`   
 ... `LocationName` works, as is, for local folders.   
*(Remote folders also contain the unc name in parentheses (\\unc name) which you would need to truncate.)

Comment: I'm trying to make this work. I tried "$app.Windows() | Select-Object LocationName", but the output only contains the Explorer Windows folder names, not the full path and folder that is displayed in the Explorer title.  I tried  "$app.Windows() | Select-Object  LocationName ... LocationName"  but that gives an error.  I'm not sure how you accomplished the code formatting in a comment, but perhaps something was lost in MikeD's last comment?

Comment: I also tried the Get-WindowTitle function from further above. That does provide an output, but it is truncated to a column width of 5 characters:  "C:..."

Comment: My goal is to capture the currently open set of explorer windows, and write out a CMD file with commands like: C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe /e, "C:\open\this\folder"

Comment: @tim11g Please post a question of your own.

Answer (score 6):

[Ansgar Wiechers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31349468/45375) is helpful, but the *title* of File Explorer windows doesn't necessarily contain the full path of the location (folder) being displayed.

Somewhat obscurely, **it is the `.Document.Folder.Self.Path` property of the window objects returned by the `.Windows()` method of the `Shell.Application` COM object that contains the full, local or UNC path**.

Therefore, the following lists the full paths of all open Explorer windows:

```
(New-Object -ComObject 'Shell.Application').Windows() | ForEach-Object { 
  $_.Document.Folder.Self.Path 
}
```

Note: Special locations such as File Explorer's "Quick access" are represented by `::`-prefixed GUIDs; e.g., `::{679F85CB-0220-4080-B29B-5540CC05AAB6}`