# How do I check if a folder at a specific path is open in Explorer with batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, path, explorer

I'd like to run `explorer FOLDERPATH` only if that specific folder is not already open.

However, there may be other Explorer windows open already with the same folder name but different paths, so I need to look at the path, not just the title. Is this possible?

Comment: The OS knows if it is open since it will refuse to delete the directory if it is in use elsewhere. However, that is likely to require more than `cmd.exe` offers. Powershell at a minimum, but maybe C, Python, Perl, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get report of all open explorer windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347905/get-report-of-all-open-explorer-windows)