# How to open a specific exe application with specific coordinates

Tags: batch-file

Currently I am modding Among Us which uses an executable to open.
In order for me to test I would need to open 4 instances of it.

I test my mods a lot and it would be great if I were to have a batch file that would open the game 4 times in a 1 second interval. After that it would move the windows into 4 separate corners.

I've done research and the only valid one I saw useful was: [Open file explorer at coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366817/open-file-explorer-at-coordinates)

Although that thread works, it either doesnt support exe files or I don't understand enough to filter the exe file.

If anyone could help me create one, that would be great!

Comment: Good news: the code you found handles all executables, you just don't know what you're doing. That said, that particular code had to be tweaked from what it normally looks like because Explorer is weird, so you probably wouldn't have figured it out by accident anyway.

Comment: So what part of the codes do I have to altar? and into what?

Comment: Bad news, Steam absolutely refuses to let me open more than once instance of the program at a time, even if I run the executable from the steamapps directory. What you're requesting appears to be impossible. If that wasn't bad enough, Among Us does this annoying thing where when it opens, it immediately closes and reopens, which makes it impossible to get a lock on the hwnd value, which is what you need to use MoveWindow.

Comment: To solve your multiple instance issue, you can create a .txt file inside `Steam > steamapps > common > Among Us` with the numbers: `945360`. It basically allows you to open multiple instances by clicking the .exe file in the directory I showed you above.

About Among Us closing and reopening, it shouldn't do that actually, I am not sure why it does that for you but mine doesn't close and reopen. Otherwise BepInEx would fail multiple times (BepInEx is the mod handler)

Comment: And how I usually open 4 instances of among us with a batch file is using `start ./"Among Us.exe"` and then `timeout /t 2` about 3 more times. But that just opens it 4 times as I want the one I requested above. lmk if you need anything else and I will try to answer with the best of my ability

Comment: The presence of a text file shouldn't do anything and doesn't, in my case - Steam still refuses to open more than one instance of the game. Is your version modified, cracked, or earlier than 2020.12.9s?

Comment: Nothing is cracked nor pirated, I am using Steam and nothing is modified! The version of among us is 2020.12.9.